# Will not show all friends in database laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel

I have made a a friends table in the database that includes the requesteeid ( id of the user who has requested to be a friend ), the inboundid ( id of the user where the friend request is going to ) and the approved column which when set false = pending and when set true = accepted, currently it seems to only one user, when i echo out the $rowsget that query's all the rows that have the profile id in either the inbound or outbound will show, when i try and loop through though I only get one, that is the latest user that has added that user( inboundee ) as a friend. Ive spent hours on this, any help is greatly appreciated!

**Database Search**

```
<?php
$rowsget = DB::table('friends')->where('requesteeid', $uid)- 
>orWhere('inboundid', $uid)->where('approved', true)->get();

if(count($rowsget) > 0){
    foreach($rowsget as $get) {
        $getrequestee = $get->requesteeid;
        $getinbound = $get->inboundid;
 }
    $rowfetchfriend = DB::table('users')->where('id', $getrequestee)- 
  >orWhere('id', $getinbound)->get(['id', 'avatar', 'username']);


?>
```

**Looping through the profiles friends**

```
   <?php
   foreach($rowfetchfriend as $loop) {
        if($loop->id != $uid) { //make sure own user isnt displayed
            echo $loop->username; // echo all usernames that are friends
        }
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: are you sure your query needs `->where('approved', true)` ?
approved are those friends that are already approved and they can not be inbound or outbound

Comment: Why do you include your business logic into your question title? Nobody will ever know what this topic is about by reading the title, because `friends` means nothing to anyone that doesn't know your project...

Comment: @Xatenev Sorry, I wasn't thinking properly, I should've replaced it with rows or something along the lines of that

Comment: @OleksandrPobuta  the query is not the issue if i echo $rowsget, the rows echo out perfectly, when i try and loop through the users info i get an error message.

Answer (score -1):

I bet your SQL will be wrong, when you use it like yiu did. Hint: You set no () to seperate your (gimme all n where (x is something or y is someother) and z is true). You do it all without the () so it will search for (x is something) or y is someother and z is true, so all rows will be found, where z is true and y is someother, so this result is wrong.

Try

```
$rowsget = DB::table('friends')
->where(function (Builder $query) use ($uid) {
  $query->where('requesteeid', $uid)
    ->orWhere('inboundid', $uid);
  })
->where('approved', true)
->get();
```

You can alsways get the SQL query by using

```
$rowsget = DB::table('friends')
->where(function (Builder $query) use ($uid) {
  $query->where('requesteeid', $uid)
    ->orWhere('inboundid', $uid);
  })
->where('approved', true)
->toSql();
```

Change your code to this:

```
$rowfetchfriend = [];
if(count($rowsget) > 0){
    foreach($rowsget as $get) {
        $getrequestee = $get->requesteeid;
        $getinbound = $get->inboundid;  
        $rowfetchfriend += DB::table('users')->where('id', $getrequestee)- 
  >orWhere('id', $getinbound)->get(['id', 'avatar', 'username']);
}
```

Your closing bracket is wrong and you have to add up your results per loop.
I would perform an other sql, where i get my results that way i want and would not fire 2 queries for this (lookup "joins").

Comment: Hi, i just tried this it didn't work, the query is not the issue if i echo $rowsget, the rows echo out perfectly, when i try and loop through the users info i get an error message.

Comment: Ok, so i need two things: The structure of your db and the exact error message, so please edit your post and this info to it

Comment: Schema::create('friends', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('requesteeid');
            $table->integer('inboundid');
            $table->boolean('approved')->default(false);
            $table->timestamps();
        });

Comment: I dont get any error message, it just doesn't loop through all my rows

Comment: Yes, it does not. I see your code in your first post and it is obvious, that you loop through rowsget and for every row, you overwrite your variable getrequestee . After that, you fire one request to your users where the id is either requesteeid or getinbound, so you will get max 2 results ;)

Comment: Sorry, I dont understand?, do i remove the loop because if i do that and set the $get->requesteeid to $rowsget->requesteeid, i get an error of this, Property [requesteeid] does not exist on this collection instance. Could you please explain thanks :))

Comment: I have made an edit to my post, see the last section

Comment: I get this error message Undefined variable: rowfetchfriend :(

Comment: Ok, initialize your variables first, see my post, i edited it

Comment: I got this error message, Object of class Illuminate\Support\Collection could not be converted to int